# Delphi [PAClient Error] Error: E6409 Cannot open file

Tags: android, delphi, 64-bit

For 2 days i have been trying to solve this problem but no luck.

I am using delphi 10.3.3 and im trying to build and deploy an android 64bit app with the "Generate Android app bundle file" option turned on. (Release configuration!)

I am getting this error:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E6409 Cannot open file "C:\Users\gaspe\Desktop\Workout Timer 2\Android64\Release\WorkoutTimer\linked_res.ap_". The system cannot find the file specified

I tried different SDKs, cleaning the project, messing with project folder permissions, updating java, starting delphi as administrator.. i even tried to delete and reinstall everything! i did everything i could imagine but without success.

The thing is that without the "Generate android app bundle file" option, it will fail also.
It will stop with this errors:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 Unable to execute '"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK\build-tools\26.0.0\aapt.exe" package -f -M "C:\Users\gaspe\Desktop\Workout Timer 2\Android64\Release\WorkoutTimer\AndroidManifest.xml" -F "C:\Users\gaspe\Desktop\Workout Timer 2\Android64\Release\WorkoutTimer\bin\WorkoutTimer-unsigned.apk" -I "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-26\android.jar" -S "C:\Users\gaspe\Desktop\Workout Timer 2\Android64\Release\WorkoutTimer\res" -A "C:\Users\gaspe\Desktop\Workout Timer 2\Android64\Release\WorkoutTimer\assets" "C:\Users\gaspe\Desktop\Workout Timer 2\Android64\Release\WorkoutTimer\library" "C:\Users\gaspe\Desktop\Workout Timer 2\Android64\Release\WorkoutTimer\classes"' (Error 1)
>   [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 C:\Users\gaspe\Desktop\Workout Timer 2\Android64\Release\WorkoutTimer\AndroidManifest.xml: error: Unable to open file for read: No such file or directory

If anyone had a similar problem and could help me solve it id really appreciate it, as i cant move on with my project. At the moment I am really lost

Comment: Just a guess. Check the project deployment. The files that aren't accessible are greyed out. You can delete them and add files that are accessible.

Comment: @nolaspeaker I just checked and no files ar greyed out in deployment, everything is "there". 
i tried messing with a few settings but still no luck. i started thinking it could be something with the signing, as "build configuration - debug" and "configuration - app store" works without problems! and just changing build configuration to release makes all this mess

Comment: Do a "Clean" and retry the build.

Comment: If debug configuration work but not release configuration then you probably have path locations declared differently in your release configuration. Also bare in mind, that some third party might have separate debug and release redistributables.

Comment: @nolaspeaker i tried already

Comment: @SilverWarior your answer def helped me solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

as @SilverWolf suggested there were paths locations declared differently.. i had AndroidManifest.xml set to .\assets\internal instead of .\ ??
Dont know how it happened but i lost 3 days because of it! Problem solved

Comment: How it happened? I'm guessing the same way as it did to me when I encountered similar problem first time myself. During development of my application I changed folder structure of my project since I added support for additional path and had some platform specific code which I moved to separate folders for easier maintainability. This also require me to change path location in project options. But since each build configuration has separate settings I only changed path settings in debug configuration but forgot that I have to make same same changes also in release configuration.